# Could not save a MySQL script (OS X)

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I created an ER graph and want to generate a script using MySQL Workbench. Doing that results in the error:

> Could not save to file 'try.sql': Failed to create file 'try.sql.JV65CX': Permission denied

What's wrong here?

Comment: You apparently don't have permission to write files to the directory you are trying to write to.

Comment: Have you tried storing the generated script in the same folder where you have your model? That should certainly succeed as MySQL Workbench is constantly doing backups. However the desktop is probably the best location, as that will give you immediate access to the file and should always succeed.

Comment: I have the same issue but in windows 10

Answer (score 3):

The issue can be with the the location of the file "try.sql" in the dialog box . Try giving the entire path where try.sql should be saved. This should solve the issue.